# What language is Wikipedia programmed in?

Tags: programming-languages, wikipedia

What language is Wikipedia programmed in?

Answer (score 25):

[Interestingly, you can answer that on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia) (It's PHP).

Comment: Section 3.2, to be more specific

Comment: Excellent a circular reference! or recursive answer! :) Darknight

Answer (score 8):

It uses [PHP](http://php.net)/[MySQL](http://mysql.com), in combination with the [MediaWiki](http://mediawiki.org) wiki software.

This is the same as all the Wikimedia projects - [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org), [Wikinews](http://en.wikinews.org), [Wikiquotes](http://en.wikiquotes.org), etc.

MediaWiki also powers many, many other sites - you can usually tell by the look-and-feel. The major one is [Wikia](http://wikia.com)

Comment: Wikileaks is, to the best of my knowledge, not a Wikimedia project.

Comment: @LucasJones [No.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:WikiLeaks_is_not_part_of_Wikipedia)

Answer (score 6):

It is programmed in PHP.

Answer (score 5):

Wikipedia runs on [MediaWiki software](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki), which uses PHP and MySQL (although by now, MediaWiki might support other SQL databases, such as PostgreSQL - you'll have to check the docs).